# Set height property of Dojo accordion content pane in ArcGIS JSAPI 3.5

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using ArcGIS JSAPI version 3.5 on my side & Dojo version is 1.9.

Everything is working fine expect the Dojo accordion content pane.

I want to set custom height of  accordion content pane.

**What I have tried:**

-I have set the property false in the code still it opens while its executing.(Please check the screen shot)

-Checked similar example on the [web site (Programmatic example)](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/AccordionContainer.html)
Link:

-Checking the API reference on my side.

Still not able to understand that why default its opening..

Any help regarding this will be great!!!

My complete code is available on `[http://jsfiddle.net/D9NDn/][2]`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: JSfiddle Link :http://jsfiddle.net/D9NDn/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? For setting a height of a ContentPane use css. If you want to hide a tool of measurement use : measurement.hideTool("location") for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do something like that?

```
<div id="closureSection" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane"  title="Distance Measurement" data-dojo-props="title:'Distance Measurement', open:false">
     <div id="measurementDiv"></div>
</div>

<div id="dataLayerSection" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" title="Content Section 02" data-dojo-props="label:'Click to Expand', open:false">
 </div>

<div id="mapLegendSection" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" title="Content Section 03" data-dojo-props="label:'Click to Expand',open:false">
 </div>

<div id="disclaimerSection" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-Props="label:'Click to Expand',open:false" title="Content Section 04">
</div>
```

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m33NL/)

I changed the ContentPanes into TitlePanes. The you can declare open:false in the data-dojo-Probs

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Thanks this is what I was trying..thanks..I will test and let you know..thanks a lot : )